# observable and computed are not working properly Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following knockout code that implements the folowing role:

> field1 + field2 -field3 = field4

```
$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});

function AppViewModel() {
this.original = ko.observable(0);
this.improvements = ko.observable(0);
this.depreciation = ko.observable(0);

this.total= ko.computed(function () {
    var total= 0;
    total= this.original() + this.improvements() - this.depreciation();
    return total;
}, this);
}
```

But for some reason it's not working properly, `this.original` is always multiplied by 10.

for example:

> 1 + 1 - 1 = 10

Any idea what can causes this?

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="calc-form">
     <label>Original Purchase Price</label>
     <input type="text" id="original" data-bind="value: original" />

     <label>+ Improvements</label>
     <input type="text" id="improvements" data-bind="value: improvements" />

     <label>- Depreciation</label>
     <input type="text" id="depreciation" data-bind="value: depreciation" />

     <input type="button" class="calcbutton" value="Calculate" />
     <input type="button" class="calcbuttonreset" value="reset" />
     <p>= Total</p>
     <span data-bind="text: total"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the value of `input` elements is always a **string**. `"1" + "1" - "1"` is `"11" - "1"` is `10` because when either operand is a string, `+` is string concatenation, not addition; but `-` is always subtraction, so it coerces its operands to numbers.

You need to parse them, via `+x` or `parseFloat(x)` or `Number(x)` or (if they're meant to be whole numbers) `parseInt(x, 10)`, etc.:

```
total = parseFloat(this.original())
        + parseFloat(this.improvements())
        - parseFloat(this.depreciation());
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});

function AppViewModel() {
  this.original = ko.observable(0);
  this.improvements = ko.observable(0);
  this.depreciation = ko.observable(0);

  this.total = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    total = parseFloat(this.original())
            + parseFloat(this.improvements())
            - parseFloat(this.depreciation());
    return total;
  }, this);
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-form">
  <label>Original Purchase Price</label>
  <input type="text" id="original" data-bind="value: original" />

  <label>+ Improvements</label>
  <input type="text" id="improvements" data-bind="value: improvements" />

  <label>- Depreciation</label>
  <input type="text" id="depreciation" data-bind="value: depreciation" />

  <input type="button" class="calcbutton" value="Calculate" />
  <input type="button" class="calcbuttonreset" value="reset" />
  <p>= Total</p>
  <span data-bind="text: total"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

If you're going to be working with numeric inputs a lot, you might want to give yourself a specific binding for them:

```
// "numValue" binding handler (just an example)
ko.bindingHandlers.numValue = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    function numValueHandler() {
      valueAccessor()(parseFloat(this.value));
    }
    $(element).on("input change", numValueHandler)
              .val(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).off("input change", numValueHandler);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    element.value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  }
};
```

Then:

```
<input type="text" id="original" data-bind="numValue: original" />
<!-- ---------------------------------------^^^^^^^^           -->
```

```js
// "numValue" binding handler (just an example)
ko.bindingHandlers.numValue = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    function numValueHandler() {
      valueAccessor()(parseFloat(this.value));
    }
    $(element).on("input change", numValueHandler)
              .val(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).off("input change", numValueHandler);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    element.value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  }
};

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});

function AppViewModel() {
  this.original = ko.observable(0);
  this.improvements = ko.observable(0);
  this.depreciation = ko.observable(0);

  this.total = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    total = this.original() + this.improvements() - this.depreciation();
    return total;
  }, this);
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-form">
  <label>Original Purchase Price</label>
  <input type="text" id="original" data-bind="numValue: original" />

  <label>+ Improvements</label>
  <input type="text" id="improvements" data-bind="numValue: improvements" />

  <label>- Depreciation</label>
  <input type="text" id="depreciation" data-bind="numValue: depreciation" />

  <input type="button" class="calcbutton" value="Calculate" />
  <input type="button" class="calcbuttonreset" value="reset" />
  <p>= Total</p>
  <span data-bind="text: total"></span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unary `+` will also coerce to number.
Also, `numValueHandler` needs to `return`.

Comment: @RoyJ: I said in the answer *"You need to parse them, via **`+x`** or..."*. No, `numValueHandler` doesn't have to return anything.

Comment: You're right on both counts. Must be too early in the morning. :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's working perfectly, thank you for the great idea to create a binding handler! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just have one problem with this `binding handler` that it doesn't let me to add a dollar sign to the fields, can I achive that with this `binding handler`?

Comment: @user3378165: It should be fairly clear from the above where you would add the dollar sign for display in the field, and where you would remove it for parsing the value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I managed to add it, it's working perfectly, thank you very much for your excellant answer!

Comment: @user3378165: Nice one!